# What happens when an evil con-hollow dies?

Tags: bleach

Aaroneiro and Szayel Appollo go to hell in an episode meant to promote The Hell Verse movie. Logically, they should split into individual souls and the evil souls go to hell and the rest are reincarnated judged on what they did before death.

Is this a canon depiction the fate of such beings? If so, how can it be explained? Why is the conhollowfied form judged for its sins?

Comment: Since it's about a movie, I would guess that no, it's not canon.